# Cannot build signed APK in Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'. java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, crashlytics

I've been working on a Flutter app and I was able to build and even sign my APK using the Android Studio dialog, successfully. For this I open the android folder in Android Studio, go on Build > Generate Signed APK.

This stopped working today with the message:

```
> Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.
> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "." + flutterVersionName + "." + flutterVersionCode)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            ndk {
//                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
//            }
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
}
```

I'm confused, why is this happening. In the past days I only edited *.dart files and didn't change the Android project at all. I still can build the debug APK using Build > Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) > Build APK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restarted my system and now everything is working again, so never mind.

Answer (score 0):

**To enable Crashlytics mapping file upload for specific product flavors:**

```
import com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsExtension

android {
 buildTypes {
   getByName("debug") {
   minifyEnabled = true

   configure<CrashlyticsExtension> {
    mappingFileUploadEnabled = false
   }

 }
}
```